# Deserialize JSON into Struct?

Tags: ruby, json

How can I deserialize a JSON string into a [Struct](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Struct.html) instead of the default (which is a [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html), something where the hash keys are accessible as methods on the object using something like `attr_accessor`s, basically.

In other words, I really want to be able to write `obj.my_json_property` to access the data.

Answer (score 4):

If [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) is acceptable (which still makes it possible to use the struct as `obj.my_json_property`, i.e. it satisfies the original requirement), use this approach:

```
require 'json'
obj = JSON.parse(json_text, object_class: OpenStruct)
puts obj.my_json_property
```

I tried with `object_class: Struct` instead, but it gives me "TypeError: allocator undefined for Struct". However, for *most* (but not all) practical purposes, OpenStruct is just fine. The major drawback is that if you mis-spell one of your property names, your code runs just fine, the value will just be nil/empty string (depending on context)... which may be a bit annoying and misleading.

It's a bit like `Hash#[]` vs `Hash#fetch` (for reference, see: http://devblog.avdi.org/2009/03/16/go-fetch/).

Comment: But why would you want to do this? `Hash` is much faster than `OpenStruct` for data access.

Comment: Sometimes, speed isn't really the most important goal. In fact, if it was, why write the code in Ruby in the first place? ;) I like real objects; the code is clearer, more beautiful that way.

Comment: A `Hash` is a real object but to each there own. If you really want a `Struct` give my answer a try

Comment: By "real object" I mean something with methods... :) Instead of having to use `Hash#[]` or `Hash#fetch` to retrieve stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reasonably quick way to turn a `Hash` into a `Struct`:

```
 class Hash
    def to_struct
        s = Struct.new(*self.keys.map(&:to_sym))
        construct = map do |k,v|
            v.is_a?(Hash) ? v.to_struct : v.is_a?(Array) ? v.join(", ") : v
        end
        s.new(*construct)
    end
 end
```

Then you can do things like:

```
h = {hello: 'world',foo: {bar: 'baz'}}
m = h.to_struct
#=> #<struct hello="world", foo=#<struct bar="baz">>
m.hello
#=> "world"
m.foo
#=> #<struct bar="baz">
m.foo.bar
#=> "baz"
```

So in your case:

```
require 'json'
obj = JSON.parse(json_text).to_struct
```

Would work fine and it deals with the nested objects as well (with some obvious handling needed for `Array` *I just didn't bother with this part as it was not really part of the question)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Struct.new` to create a new class with your desired accessors that you can pass as an `object_class` to `JSON.parse`:

```
> require 'json'
> MyStruct = Struct.new(:my_json_property)
> obj = JSON.parse('{"my_json_property": "foo"}', object_class: MyStruct)
=> #<struct  my_json_property="foo">
> obj.my_json_property
=> "foo"
```